# Why does this sink gurgle?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

This is the drain and vent for a pair of kitchen sinks, one directly above the other (2 separate apartments). (The larger pipe to the far right is a roof drain that doesn't join until underground.) Under some unknown set of circumstances, the lower sink gurgles loudly. (The upstairs unit does have a retrofitted dishwasher.)

How should I go about troubleshooting? Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

[image: upper sink]
[image: lower sink]

Comment: How long has the 'gurgling' sound been going on? Did anyone have a change in the local pluming or add new sinks, etc? "Gurgling" is from trapped air in a pipe where water is flowing but some bend or junction in the pipes is trapping air. This is water pushing into a pocket of air.

Comment: Or your vent has blockage!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the most likely cause is that waste water from the upper sink is being forced up into the vent pipe for the lower sink.

The water descends without much restriction for about nine feet and accumulates enough kinetic energy to escape its intended path through the junction of the two drains. Some of it splashes into the lower drain and some into the vent pipe. This pushes air in through the lower sink p-trap, and then, when the flood abates and the water flows back out of the lower drain and vent, it pulls air out through the lower sink p-trap.

The root cause of all this is that the join between the two sink drains is much too close to the lower sink. See the left half of the diagram below:

[image: I prowl the stack exchanges searching for excuses to draw diagrams]

You can eliminate the problem by repositioning the join between the drains to a lower location. See the right half of the diagram for one way to do this.

If you decide not to change the drains because it's a lot of trouble just to get rid of an annoying gurgling, you have my sympathy. Just run some water in the lower sink after each time it gurgles, to make sure the p-trap is filled.

However -- if you are smelling sewer gas in the lower apartment, then you must call in a professional plumber to change the drains.

Comment: Nice diagram. Op